# Pass resource from directive to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to expose a resource from directive scope to a controller scope by calling a provided in the view callback.
However the argument variable is `undefined`. What am I missing?

Here's a fiddle example: **https://jsfiddle.net/xqknpe5d/**

**View**

```
<div on-my-event="doStuff(foo)"></div>
```

**Directive**

```
App.directive('myDirective', ['$whateverModule', function($module) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      onMyEvent: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {          
      (scope.onMyEvent) && ( scope.onMyEvent('moo') );         
    }
  };
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
ctrls.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.doStuff = function(foo) {
    console.log('moo: ', foo);
  };
}]);
```

Appreciate your kind help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call function `onMyEvent` like this in your link function of your directive. You have to send object with name of parameter(`'foo'`) as key and `'moo'` as value.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {          
        (scope.onMyEvent) && ( scope.onMyEvent({foo: 'moo'}) );         
    }
```

[Read more about & binding here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/guide/directive).